# How to do a foreach loop in a Twig

Tags: twig

Here i have attached screenshot,in that 2nd section 2 rows are present. i need to display only one row with custom code condition, If i disable from admin side,it will work correctly,but i need loop condition for enable and disable to display only row. Here is my code,

```
<div class="col-md-12" >{% for module in modules %}<div class="img-responsive">
                {{ module }}
              {% endfor %}</div></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's special [loop variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) inside a loop that let's you keep track of index and more. In your case `loop.index`.

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
    {% for module in modules %}
        <div class="img-responsive">
            {# Replace 1 with a specific index you want to use as condition #}
            {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                {{ module }}
            {% else %}
                No module
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: @prasanna Can you please elaborate what the problem is if this isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @prasanna I have updated my example further, the current code have a condition and will only print the first module in the loop, else it will print "No module". I am not sure what you're asking for, please try to explain your desired output.

Comment: @prasanna Did it solve your problem? If so, please feel free to mark the answer as an accepted solutions :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, please update your question with an example of what you want as output. Please make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before doing so and follow the guidelines given

Comment: ex: array(a,b,c,d,e,f)    If we want to get (a)=>1st index means we write {% if loop.first == 1 %}, If we want to get (b)=>2nd index means we write {% if loop.index == 1 %}, If we want to get(f) last index means we write {% if loop.last == 1 %}, then how can fetch (c,d,f) index value and i need individual data

Comment: No, `loop.index` specifies where in the loop we are. If you want to get the first item (a) you write `loop.index == 1`. If you want to get the second item (b) you write `loop.index == 2`. Third item (c) `loop.index == 3` etc.